# Building a very simple mobile application (no mobile dev experience)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, mobile

I'm quite skilled with Java, Python, C++, etc. but have never done mobile development. I have used React to develop a web application before, however.

For a job, as a take-home exercise they have asked me to develop a very simple mobile application which lets the user input two numbers x and y and then show a shape with the number of sides being equal to the sum of x and y (e.g. if x = 2 and y = 3 then show a pentagon).

How can I achieve this? I don't have any mobile development experience but I really want to achieve this task.

There is no specific language stated to use (however, their company uses React Native, Firebase, Node.js and JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options for this.
The first option is to do it natively which will include knowing and skils in at least two different languages if you want to support ios and android for iOS options you have swift and objective C and for Android, you have Kotlin and Java.

Still, my recommendation is to use some hybrid approach and use something which will support iOS and Android with one codebase. Here again, you can choose several options.

ReactNative which is very common with React and I think maybe it will be your best choice.
Ionic is also a good option it is based on Cordova plugins and you write javascript. I use it with typescript + angular and it was fine.
There also some options like AppBuilder of Progress. MobileFirst of IBM(javascript). Also, ADF Mobile which is a java based(but totally not recommended).

Also if you want to support iOS you will need a mac as dev machine.

In general, my recommendation is just to start with React Native for this task, it seems like the best fit for the goal and your skils. There are a lot of crash courses for it and also nor very bad documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE will make a difference.  If Xcode/Swift:

1. Create a Single Page project (keep all defaults)
2. Build Interface with required elements
3. Code: will simply have an array or dictionary with numbers relating to shapes (use UI Image Literal for shapes)
4. Sum of numbers will present appropriate shape.